# Understanding Exercise

Tags: c

I am having trouble understanding the following question:

> Define a two dimensional array `data[12][5]` of type `double`. Initialize the elements in the first column with values from `2.0` to `3.0` inclusive in steps of `0.1`. If the first element in a row has the value of `x`, populate the remaining elements in each row with the values `1/x` `x^2`, `x^3`, `x^4`. Output the values in the array with each row on a separate line and with a heading for each column.

The part, I don't understand is where the exercise says if the first element has the value of `x`, then fill each row with...

My question: what is `x` in this context?

Comment: A parameter provided. Either from input from the user, or as a parameter to the function you have to write

Comment: `x` is the value of the first element in a row. If the first element in a row is `2`, then you should populate that row: `{ 2.0, 0.5, 4.0, 8.0, 16.0 }`.

Comment: You said that the first column will have elements from 2.0 to 3.0 in steps of 0.1 which gives 11 elements but in the first column there are 12 elements. So what about the last element ?

Comment: thanks for the feedback

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the English language, not programming.